# Multiple Values passed in IList

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

I have dropdowns and Entry controls inside a Load Funcn it is called Everytime button is clicked ! Items get added in stacklayout !

These funcn can be called many a times depending upon the user I have to pass all those values in form or rows in IEnumerable !
Now only 1 row is passing ! 2nd Row is overriding the values first row !
Here is the code:

```
public partial class Rejection2ndForm : ContentPage
    {
        StackLayout stack1 = new StackLayout { Spacing = 0, Padding = new Thickness(16, 24) };
        SfButton button, Savebutton, add, sub;
        public SQLiteConnection conn;
        BorderlessEntry ent, ent2, ent3;
        string SKUId,GradeId,DefectId;

        List<QMSRejection> DataToSave = new List<QMSRejection>();
        List<QMSRejectionChild> ChildData = new List<QMSRejectionChild>();
        
        public Rejection2ndForm(List<QMSRejection> models)
        {
            InitializeComponent ();
            conn = DependencyService.Get<Isqlite>().GetConnection();
            conn.CreateTable<UserInfo>();

            
            OuterStack.Children.Add(add);
            OuterStack.Children.Add(sub);
                               
            DataToSave = models;
        }
        
        async void Load_Function(object sender,EventArgs e)
        {
            StackLayout stack = new StackLayout { Spacing = 0, Padding = new Thickness(16, 24) };

            OuterStack.Children.Remove(add);
            OuterStack.Children.Remove(sub);

           Label label1 = new Label
            {
                Text = "SKU *",
                FontFamily = "{StaticResource Montserrat-Medium}",
                FontSize = 12,
                HeightRequest = 18,
                Margin = new Thickness(0, 24, 0, 4),
                TextColor = Color.Black
            };

           Label  label2 = new Label
            {
                Text = "Defect *",
                FontFamily = "{StaticResource Montserrat-Medium}",
                FontSize = 12,
                HeightRequest = 18,
                Margin = new Thickness(0, 24, 0, 4),
                TextColor = Color.Black
            };
        

            SfBorder border1 = new SfBorder { CornerRadius = 12, BorderWidth = 1, BorderColor = Color.Gray, BackgroundColor = Color.White };
            SfBorder border2 = new SfBorder { CornerRadius = 12, BorderWidth = 1, BorderColor = Color.Gray, BackgroundColor = Color.White };
            SfBorder border3 = new SfBorder { CornerRadius = 12, BorderWidth = 1, BorderColor = Color.Gray, BackgroundColor = Color.White };
        

            SfComboBox dropdown1 = new SfComboBox();
            SfComboBox dropdown2 = new SfComboBox();
            SfComboBox dropdown3 = new SfComboBox();

            // SKU

            dropdown1.Watermark = "Choose SKU";
            string url = AppSettingsManager.Settings["RejectionUrl"] + "GetSKUList";
            var data = await url.GetJsonAsync<List<MyClass>>();
            dropdown1.DataSource = data;
            dropdown1.DisplayMemberPath = "Text";
            dropdown1.VerticalOptions = LayoutOptions.CenterAndExpand;
            dropdown1.SelectionChanged += SKU_select;
            dropdown1.Margin = new Thickness(8, 3, 0, -3);
            dropdown1.HeightRequest = 40;
            dropdown1.TextSize = 16;
            DropDownButtonSettings settings = new DropDownButtonSettings();
            dropdown1.ShowBorder = true;
            var dropdownlabel1 = new Label();
            border1.Content = dropdown1;


            // Grades

            dropdown2.Watermark = "Choose Grade";
            string urlx = AppSettingsManager.Settings["RejectionUrl"] + "GetGradeList";
            var datax = await urlx.GetJsonAsync<List<MyClass>>();
            dropdown2.DataSource = datax;
            dropdown2.DisplayMemberPath = "Text";
            dropdown2.VerticalOptions = LayoutOptions.CenterAndExpand;
            dropdown2.SelectionChanged += Grade_select;
            border3.Content = dropdown2;

            // Defect

            dropdown3.Watermark = "Choose Defect";
            string urly = AppSettingsManager.Settings["RejectionUrl"] + "GetDefectMasterList";
            var datay = await urly.GetJsonAsync<List<MyClass>>();
            dropdown3.DataSource = datay;
            dropdown3.DisplayMemberPath = "Text";
            dropdown3.VerticalOptions = LayoutOptions.CenterAndExpand;
            dropdown3.SelectionChanged += Defect_select;
            border2.Content = dropdown3;


            // Delete Button
            button = new SfButton();
            button.CommandParameter = stack;
            button.Clicked += Delete_Clicked;
            button.Text = "Delete";
            button.Margin = new Thickness(0, 24, 0, 0);
            button.WidthRequest = 200;
            button.HeightRequest = 40;
            button.CornerRadius = 20;
            button.FontSize = 16;
            button.BorderWidth = 0;
            button.VerticalTextAlignment = TextAlignment.Center;

        
            // repairable pcs
            ent2 = new BorderlessEntry();
            ent2.BindingContext = new Binding("RepairablePcs");
            ent2.Placeholder = "0";
            ent2.Keyboard = Keyboard.Numeric;
            border5.Content = ent2;

            stack.Children.Add(label1);
            stack.Children.Add(border1);
            stack.Children.Add(label2);
            stack.Children.Add(border2);
            stack.Children.Add(label3);
            stack.Children.Add(border3);
            stack.Children.Add(label4);
            stack.Children.Add(border4);
            stack.Children.Add(label5);
            stack.Children.Add(border5);
            stack.Children.Add(button);

            OuterStack.Children.Add(stack);
            OuterStack.Children.Add(add);
            OuterStack.Children.Add(sub);

            }

        
        private void Grade_select(object sender, Syncfusion.XForms.ComboBox.SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            SfComboBox dropdown2 = sender as SfComboBox;
            var selected = (MyClass)dropdown2.SelectedItem;
            var Id = selected.Value;
            GradeId = Id;
        }

        
        
        private void Submit_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

           
            var rejchild = new QMSRejectionChild();
            rejchild.StockKeepingUnitId = SKUId;
            rejchild.QMSDefectMasterId = DefectId;
            rejchild.GradeMasterId = GradeId;
            rejchild.RepairablePics = ent2.Text.ToString();
            rejchild.NoOfPics = ent.Text.ToString();
            ChildData.Add(rejchild);

        }
```

Now on Submit click I m passing values of load funcn inside Ienumerable

```
private void Submit_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            //BorderlessEntry ent = sender as BorderlessEntry;
            //BorderlessEntry ent2 = sender as BorderlessEntry;
          

            var rejchild = new QMSRejectionChild();
            rejchild.StockKeepingUnitId = SKUId;
            rejchild.QMSDefectMasterId = DefectId;
            rejchild.GradeMasterId = GradeId;
            rejchild.RepairablePics = ent2.Text.ToString();
            rejchild.NoOfPics = ent.Text.ToString();
            rejchild.AddedDate = DateTime.Now.ToString();
            rejchild.UpdatedDate = DateTime.Now.ToString();
        
            ChildData.Add(rejchild);

        }
}
```

What I am doing wrong as it is taking only 1 row !

Comment: Make sure you are not initializing ChildData list object every time, otherwise instead of adding records, it will just keep last record inserted as list item.

Comment: So what do I have to do ?

Comment: currently where initialization has been done? If your constructor called once and not every time when item added,  then you can initialize there: Childata=new List<yourModel>(); and access it throughout

Comment: updated post have a look at the initialization !

Comment: if you call `Load_Function` multiple times your global variables `ent` and `ent2`, `GradeId` etc will only point to the **LAST** set of fields added

Comment: So what can I do to remove this issue ?

Comment: this is not a simple code issue, it is a fundamental design flaw.  Personally, I would suggest instead of having multiple forms displayed at the same time, just create a single form that adds a new item to your list.

Comment: Actually is was designed like this because we have to add items to stacklayout only if add button is clicked.so design was thought like that !

Comment: Well, it's a bad design.  Sometimes as a programmer you have to push back when you are handed a bad design.  Another option would be to use a ListView/CollectionView and a data binding.

Comment: Sir cann't we do anything to this ?

Comment: I'm sure there is but I don't have all day to spend on helping you fix it.  If you have multiple forms and only one Submit button, then you will have to loop through every form and add it's data when you click submit.

Comment: actually it depends on the user whether he want to add a form or not ? If he wants he will load a form ! then add data to Ilist

Comment: see the thing is,in load function you are declaring new stack layout every time. so no record is there that whats previous record in stack layout.

Comment: so you need to declare your stack and outstack on top along with that stacklayout1 decalration.
So everytime you add in stack it will keep older records plus add a new one

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the question, using Loops and If else statements !Really happy to solve it of my own !